Who is the real artist of this well-known cover of Honky Tonk Women by the Rolling Stones?
Note
Because this is partially an ID question, which aren't allowed on this site anymore, please read this meta post before voting to close this question. (I have also already asked this question on r/NameThatSong, but to no avail.)
Question
There is this pretty famous video on YouTube of people dancing to a cover of the song Honky Tonk Women by the Rolling Stones. But despite the video's famousness, it's increadibly difficult to find the artist of the song.
According to YouTube, the supposed artist is "CatCalmer", and if you klick on the auto-generated link in the description, you get to this video. But I'm pretty sure there is no artist by the name of CatCalmer since I couldn't find anything about them on the internet (except the video). The CatCalmer video is also obviously an audio rip-off from the dace recording. You can for example hear people cheering in the background, and there is a small audio defect around the 2:05 mark where the audio briefly breaks.
Now curiously, on the cover art that is also automatically linked by YouTube, it claims that the actual artist is "Miesha" and the song is called "Stepper":

If you look for this artist, you actually find this song on Spotify, Amazon Music, and several other platforms. But this is just another audio rip-off from the dance recording, and any other songs by Miesha are also completely different. It is also the version you will find if you for example try to look for the song using Shazam.
So it seems impossible to find the original cover artist without actually knowing who they are. Since the dance recording is quite old, and one of the dancers apparently died in 2009, this cover version must be at least around 15-16 years old. I already listened through many, many other cover versions on Spotify trying to find it, but no luck.
The only other explanation that I currently have is that the cover version was actually a live recording by a small band that never cared to make their music publicly available.
But in any case, I'm fairly certain that neither Miesha nor CatCalmer are the original cover artists of this song.

It would be better (and nicer) if you were to wait for an answer on Meta before posting your question here anyway. Your question is well-informed, and you put a proper amount of effort into it, but there are many covers used in many videos on YouTube, of which I'm sure it's hard to find out who the artist is, and this is still, ultimately, an ID question.

Sorry, I did not mean to be disrespectful. I decided to post my question here because quite literally only a handful of people had looked at my meta question so far, and it doesn't seem like it would get any more attention in the future. How long do you suggest I should have waited for a response before posting here? Again, no disrespect, I mean this in the most sincere way.

May 3rd is a long time to wait, you're right. This SE site is quite slow, everything takes a lot longer than on most other sites on the platform, so I totally get your impatience (if it even can still be considered that) now :) I will relay my comment to that Meta post, and expand on it a little.

Thank you, much appreciated!

That's Travis Tritt, for sure.  Looks like they threw some nonsense in to confuse the algorithm.




Wow, thank you so much! I didn't expected this to get solved anymore.

You're welcome.  I know how you felt, I've been there too.
